# replace text with string

Tags: java, android, html

I have to replace **"font-size"** value in my `HTML` text with my required text size for my android app.

I am getting

> font-size: 26.2101px;
>
> font-size: 0.9em
>
> font-size: 31px;

I want to replace **"font-size"** attribute with value **"16px"**. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using RegEx

```
(font-size: \\d+.?\\d+((em)?(px)?))
```

> Example

```
     String s="font-size: 26.2101px;";
     String regEx="(font-size: \\d+.?\\d+((em)?(px)?))"; 
     s=s.replaceAll(regEx,"16px");
```

Comment: Thanks @NJ its working, some change in your code for better output.  String regEx="(font-size: \\d+.?\\d+((em)?(px)?))";

Comment: Welcome ,Glad to help you, please do vote up and accept

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve this with a regular expression.

Something in the form of font-size: [0-9]*.?[0-9]*(px|em)

For more details on [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) you can check out this page:

To Test this expression, you can go [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Regular Expression to replace your text as

```
String htmlString = Html.fromHtml("yourHtmlString").toString();
String regex = "font-size: \\(\\[0-9\\]*\\(.*\\)\\[0-9\\]+px\\);";
htmlString.replaceAll(regex, "font-size: 30px");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly then you are probably looking for something like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    /* Text To-Be Replaced */
    String myTextString = "font-size: 26.2101px;\nfont-size: 0.9em\nfont-size: 31px;";
    /* Regex Replace */
    System.out.println(myTextString.replaceAll("font-size: [0-9]+px;","font-size: 16px;");
}
```

Output:

```
font-size: 26.2101px;
font-size: 0.9em
font-size: 16px;
```